# Xilinx SDK/Eclipse Debug Configuration Issues

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xilinx, xilinx-edk

I'm using the Xilinx SDK (built on top of Eclipse) to write an application built using FreeRTOS running on a MicroBlze softcore processor, and am having issues trying to debug both the main source code and library source code simultaneously.  I would like to be able to step into functions that are in libraries, when called form the main source.

The following is  a snip of the application's heirarchy in eclipse. HYGRO_TEST is where my main function lives.

[image]

I wish to be able to step into the libraries that live in /microblaze_0/lib and libsrc while debugging my main function. Naievely placing a breakpoint in the library's source file through the debug view produces the error:
[image]

It is my impression that what I am trying to do is normally accomplished though the debug configuration, by adding a new source lookup path. I'm not sure how to accomplish this, as the only option for adding a source lookup path seems to be Path Mapping, bu I am not certain that providing the relative path to both the compilation and file system path has any effect. When I do so, the error persists.

Another alternative solution I found in my research of the issue was adding the library's source directory as an additional source location in my application's properties as such:

[image]

This causes some catastrophic errors with the project make, as no binaries are generated after doing this, it seems to remove the current configuration of libraries / library paths in the project properties, other undesired effects are unknown.

Again, the desired effect is to be able to step through library functions called from the main. Is there a way to tell the compiler to include debug info for the libs? some of the libs are in .a format, and some are simply .h and .c files. Ideally I would like to be able to step through all of them, but if I could step through just the .h and .c files that would suffice.

I am using the System Debugger, not GDB.

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by changing compilation settings for the project containing the libraries. Added -O0 and -g3 in the last_try bsp config.

[image]